# Select date range between bookings

Tags: mysql

I have a bookings for properties table, the schema being:

```
property_id, start_date, end_date
```

This has a list of the property IDs (referenced in another table) and the start_date and end_date of every booking for each property.

What I'm trying to work out is a query that would show all properties (DISTINCT) available for a 7 day stay within the next 28 days.

I can't work out how I'd begin to structure this query.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a cross join (join the table against itself) and compare the finish date of one record against the start date of another record of the same property.

Quick sample to get you started (missing the within 28 days condition and not guaranteed to work in every case):

```
create table bookings(id int, start datetime, finish datetime);

insert into bookings values (1, '2015-05-18','2015-05-23');
insert into bookings values (1, '2015-05-25','2015-06-01');
insert into bookings values (2, '2015-05-18','2015-05-29');
insert into bookings values (2, '2015-06-15','2015-06-21');

select distinct a.id  
from bookings a cross join bookings b 
where 
a.id = b.id and a.start != b.start and datediff(a.start,b.finish) >= 7;
```

Comment: I've got as far as `SELECT DISTINCT a.property_id FROM availability a CROSS JOIN availability b WHERE a.property_id = b.property_id AND a.start_date != b.start_date AND datediff(a.start_date,b.end_date) >= 7 AND a.start_date < NOW() + INTERVAL 28 DAY AND a.end_date > NOW() + INTERVAL 28 DAY;` which is returning results.... but not the correct ones?!